# Oracle - PLSQL / Insert a line if the update has been made

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to make a log about an update. So i want to insert the log if the update query has been made.

```
    UPDATE DEPOT_IMPORT SET DEPOT_IMPORT.CD_REGATE = 
      (SELECT CONTROLE_IMPORT_REGATE.NEW_REGATE
       FROM CONTROLE_IMPORT_REGATE 
       WHERE DEPOT_IMPORT.CD_REGATE = CONTROLE_IMPORT_REGATE.OLD_REGATE)
WHERE DEPOT_IMPORT.CD_REGATE in (SELECT DISTINCT OLD_REGATE FROM CONTROLE_IMPORT_REGATE);
-- INSERTION AVIS FONCTIONNEL
INSERT INTO DEPOT_AVIS_FONCTIONNEL VALUES (p_id_depot,'Modification du regate car obsolète','AFO505');
```

Comment: I'd probably use a trigger here.

Comment: Ok thanks, so now i've to learn the trigger :)

Comment: Is this in PL/SQL? If so, you could always do `v_rowcount := sql%rowcount;` after the update and then do a check for `v_rowcount > 0` to decide whether to do the insert or not. This assumes that there will be no updates to the table except by this code.

Answer (score 1):

> Ok thanks, so now i've to learn the trigger :)

`Triggers` are very helpful when you do `logging/auditing`. Hence learning `trigger` should not be a overhead.

See below demo which simplifies your requirement.

-- Table created and inserted a record for instance

```
CREATE TABLE depot_import ( cd_regate   NUMBER);

INSERT INTO depot_import VALUES ( 1 );
```

-- Created trigger on table depot_import to handle `logging` i.e inserting into 'depot_avis_fonctionnel'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trk_upd BEFORE
    UPDATE ON depot_import
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO depot_avis_fonctionnel VALUES (
        :new.cd_regate,
        'Modification du regate car obsolète',
        'AFO505'
    );
END;
```

Updating table:

```
UPDATE depot_import
    SET
        cd_regate = 3
WHERE cd_regate = 1;

Commit;
```

`Records` gets inserted via `triggers`.

--Selecting

```
SQL>  SELECT * FROM depot_avis_fonctionnel;
      COL1 COL2                                                                             COL3
---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         3 Modification du regate car obsolète                                              AFO505
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE DEPOT_IMPORT SET DEPOT_IMPORT.CD_REGATE = ...
```

What is the *log*? Is it

```
INSERT INTO DEPOT_AVIS_FONCTIONNEL ...
```

---

Anyway: if you use it as part of a PL/SQL block, then you could do something like this:

```
begin
  update depot_import set ...

  -- Log the update:
  insert into log_table (cdate, text, rows_affected) values
    (sysdate, 'Table DEPOT_IMPORT has been updated', sql%rowcount);

  insert into dep DEPOT_AVIS_FONCTIONNEL ...

  -- Log the insert:
  insert into log_table (cdate, text, rows_affected) values
    (sysdate, 'Table DEPOT_AVIS_FONCTIONNEL has been inserted', sql%rowcount);
end;
```

---

If you use pure SQL, then yes - you'll probably use a trigger. It fires for each table separately, so you'll have to write as many triggers as there are tables you modify.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for you're answer. Yes im using the PLSQL Block and yes my log datatable is DEPOT_AVIS_FONCTIONNEL. I'll try ur code :)